# Why does MongoDB no longer allow using $set and $unset with an empty document?

Tags: mongodb

I just updated from MongoDB version 2.2 to version 2.6 and discovered that you can no longer use `$set` and `$unset` operators in the `update` method with an empty dictionary.  For example, calling `db.mytable.update({field:value}, {$set:{}})` used to just leave the document unmodified, but now it raises an error, saying that the value to `$set` can't be empty.

Can someone justify why this is an improvement over the old behavior?  For me, it just creates an unnecessary need for extra logic, such as `if` statements to make sure the value isn't empty before attempting to `update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SERVER-12266](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12266) contains an official explanation. In particular this [comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12266?focusedCommentId=485843&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-485843):

> I spoke to Scott Hernandez about this today, and he explained the new strictness around empty modifiers is intended to alert users that were inadvertently sending over empty updates. [...]

Whether that's reasonable or not, I can't say. I suppose you could work around it by appending `_id` (or another constant field) to the `$set` value by default.

Comment: Are you saying that if I `$set` the `_id` field then it will be silently ignored and not actually modify the field?  Can I use the same trick for `$unset`?  If so that's a fair workaround, albeit hellishly confusing for someone else trying to read my code who isn't familiar with this quirk.

Comment: If you `$set` the `_id` field to its existing value (thus not modifying it), then yes (returns `"nModified" : 0`). For $unset you could use a field/key that will never exist to workaround an empty dictionary.

Comment: Wasn't there a change that prevented any existance of _id in the update document?

Comment: @Sammaye According to SERVER-12266 it's the other way around. It wasn't allowed in 2.4 but works in 2.5+. It also works for me on 2.6.3 .

Answer (score 1):

This was bassically a user change that:

> is intended to alert users that were inadvertently sending over empty updates

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12266?focusedCommentId=485843&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-485843