# MongoDB 5.0 no longer allows to update an exsisting document with empty one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying following query in MongoDB v5.0
db.test.insertOne({"test":"value"})
db.test.update({"test":"value"},{}) ... this throws an error saying "Uncaught MongoDriverError: Update document requires atomic operators" but earlier(MongoDB 4.4.2) this used to pass and update the document to empty. why this is no longer allowed ?

I have checked this below question, but this talks about $set,$unset operators and above query seemed to be working fine.
[Why does MongoDB no longer allow using $set and $unset with an empty document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814326/why-does-mongodb-no-longer-allow-using-set-and-unset-with-an-empty-document)
. PSI the image stating the above issue :-
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1tdN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, you made a mistake in your testing.

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos>  db.test.insertOne({"test":"value"}) 
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("611e6ba92bf1d59775386625")
}
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.test.update({"test":"value"},{})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("611e6ba92bf1d59775386625") }
```

Comment: Interesting. In which version did you try this query.
I tried it again in MongoDB Web shell and it failed again on this link :- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/ ... here they have provided an option to try the update query in the website it self.  Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: You are missing mcve in your question. Add that along with exact versions that *you* tested on and complete results.

Comment: Added the info. Thanks btw

Comment: got it! so the problem is with the website where they are allowing us to run MongoDB v5.0 quires directly. i just tried these quires by installing latest version(MongoDB shell version v5.0.2 , MongoDB shell version v5.0.2 ) in PC and it worked fine.

Comment: The issue @MarkenStyne is referring is with the _web shell_ (its an interactive web shell on the MongoDB Manual web site https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/tutorial/update-documents/). The update fails as reported in the web shell (for the web shell versions 4.4 and 5.0, but not with v4.2).